# \cite{*} not working, no bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, thesis, bibdesk

I'm using this template style found here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis. 
I used Bibdesk to create my .bib file.
The citekeys weren't working, I was simply getting [ ?] for every citation, so I replaced them all with hand done references, and am trying to create the bibliography using 
\cite{*}. However, it's not creating a bibliography and I'm getting no error messages explaining why.

This is the excerpt from the main.tex file that references bibliographical stuff. I've been reading through similar problems but haven't found anything that worked for me. Thanks for any help!

```
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"
\nocite{*} % pulls everything in the bibliography file.
```

Comment: You have to run `bibtex yourfile` where `yourfile.tex` is the name of your main tex file. Sequence is `pdflatex` `bibtex` `pdflatex` `pdflatex`. Append yourfile in all the four.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This was informative, but I need clarification. My .bib file automatically opens with Bibdesk, I didn't know it could be run. I opened it with TeXshop (What I'm using) and ensured that it was specified as a Bibdesk file. Now running that comes up with several errors, it complains that it has no \citation commands, no \bibdata commands, and no \bibstyle commands. But my main.tex file is handling all that (I thought). I ran them in the order you suggested, but my main.tex (it's really called that) still has no errors, and no bibliography. What am I missing?

Comment: Open your `main.tex` in texshop`. Choose `pdflatex` and compile. Now choose `bibtex` and compile. Is that what you are doing? I don't have texshop.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I run the main.tex file as both a pdflatex and bibtex file in alternation. I wasn't following that part. Thanks!